# Where NE (Microsoft New Executable) specification can be found?

Tags: windows, executable, specifications

I'm trying to find anything about an internal structure of `.fon` files. I was unable to found any specification for it, but I figured out that `.fon` files have almost same structure as `.dll` .

I found [Microsoft PE and COFF Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx/) but it describes only PE (Portable Executable) format, while `.fon` files use NE (New Executable).

NE is older and I'm unable to find any spec for it. Does it even exist? And if so, where I can find it?

Comment: It was a format for 16-bit executable files.  Al Gore had not invented the Internet yet.  If the [Wikipedia link](http://benoit.papillault.free.fr/c/disc2/exefmt.txt) doesn't help then you'll have to visit a museum.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! I had never thought that it's so ancient. :D (Repost this as an answer if you want me to accept it.)

Comment: This old Win3-era article from the Microsoft Knowledge Base provides some technical information on the NE file header: https://web.archive.org/web/20070222091910/https://support.microsoft.com/kb/65122